# JetBrains DotTrace buttons grayed out

Tags: .net, profiling, dottrace

I'm trying to profile a .NET C# web application on my local machine. To do so, I've loaded the solution in Visual Studio 2013 and selected **dotTrace -> Profile Startup Project** from the main Visual Studio menu.

That fires up dotTrace, but when the service starts, I can't use any of the dotTrace buttons, they're all grayed out. See below:

[image]

My application is running under IIS Express is at `http://localhost:49824`. I'm using dotTrace 5.5.2 and Visual Studio 2013. Anyone know why I can't profile my application?

Answer (score 8):

Shutdown IIS express from the task bar before running "Profile Application..." or "Profile Startup Project"

Answer (score 0):

This happens in IIS if you have not started your application. I attach to w3wp.exe, and the buttons are greyed out. But I navigate to the URL of my application and they are enabled.